# Extract time series from CFSV2 Google Earth Engine Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, pandas, data-frame, google-earth-engine-python-api, python-3.7

I'm trying to export to a dataframe the time series of the CFS model for the maximum temperature since 2000 for any latitude/longitude, but I have a Time Out problem. So, I tried a for each year and after doing an append and then joining everything, but after the 2 year it just timeouts too.

```
import pandas as pd
import geemap, ee
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geemap, ee
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
        ee.Initialize()
except Exception as e:
        ee.Authenticate()
        ee.Initialize()

poi = ee.Geometry.Point(127.072483, 37.515817).buffer(200)

viirs = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/CFSV2/FOR6H").filterDate('2000-01-01','2022-01-01')

def poi_mean(img):
    mean = img.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry=poi, scale=30).get('Maximum_temperature_height_above_ground_6_Hour_Interval')
    return img.set('date', img.date().format()).set('mean',mean)

poi_reduced_imgs = viirs.map(poi_mean)

nested_list = poi_reduced_imgs.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(2), ['date','mean']).values().get(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(nested_list.getInfo(), columns=['date','mean'])
```

Second way:

```
years=[2000,2001,2002, 2003... to 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021] # for example

df=pd.DataFrame()
temp = pd.DataFrame()
for year in years:
    print(year)
    viirs = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/CFSV2/FOR6H").filterDate(str(year)+'-01-01',str(year+1)+'-01-01')
    
    poi_reduced_imgs = viirs.map(poi_mean)
    
    nested_list = poi_reduced_imgs.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(2), ['date','mean']).values().get(0)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(nested_list.getInfo(), columns=['date','mean'])
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
    df = df.set_index('date')
    df = df.resample('D').max()
    
    temp=temp.append(df)
    df=pd.DataFrame()
```